# What are the disk requirements for Android's AOSP variant for both downloading and compilation?

Tags: android

I am trying to download the source code for android through "repo sync".

But its taking too much time. Please can anyone tell me what's the complete size of Android AOSP source code?

Answer (score 5):

The size is 25 GB and you need over 50 GB to build it .

Source https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

**Edit 07/10/2021**

Per @JiThin comment below:

At least 250GB of free disk space to check out the code and an extra 150 GB to build it. If you conduct multiple builds, you need additional space.

Comment: This answer is outdated. Following are the latest requirements.
"At least 250GB of free disk space to check out the code and an extra 150 GB to build it. If you conduct multiple builds, you need additional space."
https://source.android.com/setup/build/requirements